# How to get a particular value value from JSON and bind the value in HTML elements in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable which contain JSON value. Now i need to get the each and every value from JSON and bind the same to respective HTML elements. Below is my code:

```
var sess = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
alert(sess['EmpName']);
```

I just getting **Undefined** in the alert. Even I also tried like below,

```
 var sess = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
 var ses = JSON.parse(sess);
 alert(ses.EmpName);
```

For this also I get **Undefined**.How to get the value from JSON and bind the same in HTML elements using angular2.
I get the below value by doing `console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('session')));`[image: Its my value]

below is the which i get .`[{"CompanyCode":1,"EmpSKNo":111,"EmpNumber":"sf","EmpName":"sdfdsf  K","DataScope":null,"ProgramName":"Cons - ","ProgramCode":56345,"ProgramScope":"51","DesignationCode":"756","Designation":"dfgg           ","GradeCode":34,"DesignationLevel":"100","LocationCode":154,"LocationName":"ere","LocationScope":"9C.1","UserCode":"sdf","AliasFlag":"0","GroupCode":0,"GroupName":null,"NTId":"df","EmpVersion":54,"MngrSKNo":"434","EmailId":"sgfsg.K@sdfdf.COM","EMPGEO":"IND01","EMPMANAGERPKID":"434","EMPLOYEEPKID":"5345","EMPLEVEL":"162012.26.20"}]`

Comment: This means that there is no EmpName property in your JSON. Use your debugger. Or just plain simple console.log() statements, to see what your object actually is.

Comment: ooops i did not see your question's second part. can you post what do you get when you try console.log( JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('session')));

Comment: @JBNizet I had tried **EmpName** is in sess. I'm getting the value in console.

Comment: @Vijay then it should show in alert as well. you are doing something wrong

Comment: @Sajeetharan I had updated my question. Kindle check it out now.

Comment: it seems to be an array. can you post what you get when you do console.log( JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('session')));

Comment: @Sajeetharan check out the image in my question. That is what I get.

Comment: can you post here when you do this console.log( sessionStorage.getItem('session'));

Comment: @Sajeetharan Check out my question at the bottom.

Comment: So, as you can see, what you have is not an object. It's an array. And the first element of the array is an object with an EmpName attribute. So, either you should have an object, and you need to fix the code storing the object in the session storage, or you should have an array (but why?), and you should thus use `ses[0].EmpName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse to Object

```
var sess = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('session'));
alert(sess['EmpName']);
```

As i mentioned in the comment, so you need this.

```
var sess = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
 var ses = JSON.parse(sess);
 alert(ses[0].EmpName);
```